# Onchange event can't open JavaScript function due to "no function-object"

Tags: javascript, xslt

I want to call a JavaScript function with a checkbox. Everytime I click the checkbox an error occurs: "Value of property "function" is null or not defined, no function-object". This error only appears on Internet Explorer 11. Many people here have problems that you have to check twice for working but my JavaScript function doesn't even start.

I have tried to run a completely empty script but same error.
I have also tried `onclick` but same problem.

Here is my xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head><title>Secrets</title></head>

<body onload="script_for_all_functions();">

<table id="myTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="150" style="background-color:e2e2e2"></col>         
        </colgroup>
        <tr  style ="background-color:a5a5a5">
            <th rowspan="2">plane
                <select id="modelRangeDropdown" onchange="script_for_all_functions()">
                     <option selected="selected">All</option>
                     <xsl:for-each select="logstore/Fahrzeug">
                        <option>
                         <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                        </option>
                     </xsl:for-each>                    
                </select>                   
            </th>   
            <th colspan="2" width="330">date</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Secret
                <input type="checkbox" id="identicalSecrets" onchange="script_for_all_functions()"></input>
                <label for="identicalSecrets">hide identical secrets</label>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th align="center" style="background-color:a5a5a5">begin</th>
            <th align="center" style="background-color:a5a5a5">end</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane/trigger">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="../Name"/></td>
                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="secret"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/C:/eclipse-workspace/adclasses/src/inbox/script_for_all_functions.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Kind of makes sense. Is `script_for_all_functions` an actual function or is it just the name of your script ? Could you provide the contents of that script file ? Thanks.

Comment: I have just edited my question. ``script_for_all_functions`` is an actual function. As I edited that even a completely empty function does not start I think that it is not needed to provide content of my function is it? Thanks

Comment: If the problem happens only in IE11, then I guess (_guess_) that Explorer doesn't find the script (wrong format of `src`, maybe?). Check on the Network tab in the dev tools.

Comment: I would recommend doing the following. Add a script right after script_for_all_functions.js with the following code (Don't forget to remove the `onchange` on the checkbox). `<script>window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById("identicalSecrets").onchange = script_for_all_functions }</script>`. The reason for the script is that it's possible that IE sets `script_for_all_functions` immediately to the `onchange` without previously understanding what that function is (since your script gets loaded later)

Comment: Also can you confirm this is only happening for your `checkbox` and not the other elements that seem to be using the same script ?

Comment: However, if you can't find a solution... then detect if IE11 or lower and provide a link to download chrome or firefox xD.

Comment: No this is not only happening for my checkbox but also for my drop-down-menu. But I think if I would find a solution for one of them then I could use it for the other one as well. I will try your recommendation for the checkbox. A link for chrome or firefox is not sufficient :D

Comment: I have just tested your code. It's not working. Error is "script is not defined"